# UnsupportedOperationsException while attempting to shuffle an ArrayList without built-in class

Tags: java

As I said, I am attempting to create an ArrayList ,then write in a shuffler, I am using the Fisher-Yates, homework says no built-ins. However, every time I run it I get the UnsupportedOperationsException. I tried to read the line that it gives as well as many answers on Google, however I am still not sure what is causing the error.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CardShuffler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        cardDeck deckCards = new cardDeck();
        deckCards.newMethod(deckCards.deckOfCards);
        //System.out.println(deckOfCards);

    }
}
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class cardDeck {

    ArrayList deckOfCards;

    public cardDeck() {

        ArrayList<String> deckOfCards = new ArrayList();
        deckOfCards.add("JC");
        deckOfCards.add("QC");
        deckOfCards.add("KC");
        deckOfCards.add("AC");
        deckOfCards.add("JD");
        deckOfCards.add("QD");
        deckOfCards.add("KD");
        deckOfCards.add("AD");
        deckOfCards.add("JH");
        deckOfCards.add("QH");
        deckOfCards.add("KH");
        deckOfCards.add("AH");
        deckOfCards.add("JS");
        deckOfCards.add("QS");
        deckOfCards.add("KS");
        deckOfCards.add("AS");

        //String cardDeck = deckOfCards.toString();

        //System.out.println("Before shuffling " + cardDeck);
        //int numCards = deckOfCards.size();

        //System.out.println(numCards);
        System.out.println("Before shuffling " + "\n" + deckOfCards);

    }

    public ArrayList getDeckOfCards() {
        return deckOfCards;
    }

    //Now shuffle the cards

    public void newMethod(List<ArrayList> deckOfCards) {

        //int numCards = deckOfCards.size();
        int numCards = 16;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
            int change = i + random.nextInt(numCards - i);
            Collections.swap(deckOfCards, i, change);
            System.out.println("After shuffling " + random);

        }
    }

}
```

I am also supposed to have the elements in a 4x4 array,

```
XX XX XX XX
XX XX XX XX
XX XX XX XX
XX XX XX XX
```

but I am beginning to think that is a joke, looked everywhere and it seems VERY difficulty.

Thanks.

```
Before shuffling 
[JC, QC, KC, AC, JD, QD, KD, AD, JH, QH, KH, AH, JS, QS, KS, AS]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.get(int)" because "l" is null
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.swap(Collections.java:501)
    at cardDeck.newMethod(cardDeck.java:53)
    at CardShuffler.main(CardShuffler.java:9)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**EDIT**
I realized what was causing the UnsupportedOperationsException, fixed it (I had an int in my swap, instead of my Arraylist).
However, now I am getting a null error, it says "l" is null, I dont have an "l" in my code.
**EDIT AGAIN**
I found out that the ''null'' is due to the "public void newMethod(ArrayList deckofCards), the deckOfCards is null. I thought I had declared all the elements in my constructor?

Comment: Please share the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Ajinkya, good call. Should be up there now

Comment: You should add `this.deckOfCards = deckOfCards;` to the end of the constructor.

Comment: Null pointer is because desk of card is null when you pass it to new method. Also, I did not understand the intension behind passing the deckofcards to the newMethod. newMethod is a mutator of the state of the object. You don't have to pass that state from outside the object. Object has it's state (deckOfCards) and mutator method should change it by accessing the member variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class CardShuffler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        cardDeck deckCards = new cardDeck();

        //System.out.print(cardDeck.deckOfCards);

        cardDeck.shuffleArray(cardDeck.deckOfCards);
        for (Object i : cardDeck.deckOfCards) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }


    }
}
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class cardDeck {

    static ArrayList deckOfCards;

    public cardDeck() {

        List<String> deckOfCards = new ArrayList<>();
        deckOfCards.add("JC");
        deckOfCards.add("QC");
        deckOfCards.add("KC");
        deckOfCards.add("AC");
        deckOfCards.add("JD");
        deckOfCards.add("QD");
        deckOfCards.add("KD");
        deckOfCards.add("AD");
        deckOfCards.add("JH");
        deckOfCards.add("QH");
        deckOfCards.add("KH");
        deckOfCards.add("AH");
        deckOfCards.add("JS");
        deckOfCards.add("QS");
        deckOfCards.add("KS");
        deckOfCards.add("AS");

        //String cardDeck = deckOfCards.toString();

        //System.out.println("Before shuffling " + cardDeck);
        //int numCards = deckOfCards.size();

        //System.out.println(numCards);
        System.out.println("Before shuffling " + "\n" + deckOfCards);

        this.deckOfCards = (ArrayList) deckOfCards;

    }

    public ArrayList getDeckOfCards() {
        return deckOfCards;
    }

    //Now shuffle the card

    public static void shuffleArray(List<Integer> a) {
        int numCards = a.size();
        //int numCards = 16;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
            int index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            Collections.swap(a, i, index);
        }
    }

    public static void swap(List<Integer> deckOfCards, int i, int change) {
        int helper = deckOfCards.get(i);
        deckOfCards.set(i, deckOfCards.get(change));
        deckOfCards.set(change, helper);
    }


}
```

Output:

```
[JC, QC, KC, AC, JD, QD, KD, AD, JH, QH, KH, AH, JS, QS, KS, AS]
[JC, QC, KC, AC, JD, QD, KD, AD, JH, QH, KH, AH, JS, QS, KS, AS]JD
AS
JH
AD
QC
KC
KS
QD
AC
JC
JS
KD
QH
KH
AH
QS
```

So I fixed the shuffle part of my problem with the change in the coding.
Now I am stuck on the formatting during print, as said I need it to be formatted (including the preshuffle) as follows

```
xx xx xx xx
xx xx xx xx
xx xx xx xx
xx xx xx xx
```

Comment: Well, you are using a *raw type*: `ArrayList`. **Don't do that.** `ArrayList` requires a *generic type argument*, which you didn't provide. You should rewrite it to `ArrayList<String>` (or better: `List<String>`).

Comment: Right, never raw dog it...which ArrayList do I need to change? Is it the first one? The "static ArrayList deckOfCards" ?